# Reference request on introductory actuarial science.

Tags: book-recommendation, actuarial-science

I am a MSc. student in economics student and this semester am going to take a course on stochastic processes for life insurance, consisting of finite variation processes, markov, semi-markov processes, martingale and inference on counting processes.
 I have no real prior knowledge on insurance, apart from the usual microeconomical analysis of insurance, and would like to know what introductory knowledge on insurance should I have to frame the mathematics with the actual insurance part. If you could possibly recommend some introductory books on actuarial sciences to contextualize myself, it would be amazing. Thank you.

ps: There is no real actuarial sciences stack, so this seemed the most suitable community to make this question.

Comment: My recommendation would be to check the [Casualty Actuarial Society's](http://www.casact.org/admissions/exams/) and [Society of Actuaries'](https://www.soa.org/education/exam-req/) exams and exam syllabi. Often, these have reading lists attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent book I would recommend is *"Statistical Methods with Applications to Demography and Life Insurance"* by Professor Estate Khmaladze.

Professor Khmaladze is a very renowned statistician who studied alongside Kolmogorov in Moscow, and has worked with very well known mathematicians such as  Kiyoshi Itô, the father of modern stochastic calculus.

The book is written to give you a solid mathematical foundation however, so if you'd prefer a more applied statistics themed book (ie. less formal maths and more heuristic arguments) you may wish to look elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The mathematics does not really worry me, I am going to cover quite a bit of the measure-theoretical probability and actually stochastic calculus too, for continuous time finance! What I am really searching for is a book which introduces me to concepts or ideas needed to contextualize the stochastic processes in life (and non-life) insurance!

Comment: This book is much more concerned with the applied aspect (ie. Kaplan–Meier process), though it explains in detail the mathematics it relies on and outlines various proofs, along with real world examples of the statistics explained. If you are interested in stochastics in finance, I would recommend "Essentials of Stochastic Finance" by Shiryaev. Very big and detailed book (approx 800 pages), explains in detail various aspects of financial assets. The book is also available free online if you google search. Arguably the best book for introductory stochastic finance.